# Unexplained PHP error (Internal Server Error 500)

Tags: php, linux, apache, ftp, chown

I recently moved my site over from a shared web host to a VPS, and configured apache2/vsftpd and stuff.

After a day of messing with everything, I finally got it all to work, however, I am having issue with loading a PHP file in browser.

PHP is displaying no errors, and when I hit `F12` in chrome, I see a console log flash while loading saying `GET: [mydomain]/api/myfile.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I thought this had something to do with what I was trying to do in the file, but it worked perfectly when in the page where the form is and jQuery was calling that.

However, since I wanted to return specific messages (and just those messages), I wanted it on an empty page so I could just echo them out.

So, I created a new page, uploaded it via `vsftpd` and opened it with my browser, since I wasn't POSTing anything I was expecting it to echo "No POST data", as I had made it do when `$_POST['userStatus']` isn't set, but got just an empty white page.

I tried changing the file to just be 
`<?php echo "Test"; ?>` but that didn't work either. I  am getting the same errors.

I thought maybe it might be the permissions of `www-data` not being able to access it,

so I did `chown -R www-data /home/myuser/mysite/public_html`, and restarted apache2, but still no luck.
It actually disallowed my FTP user to continue uploading, so I had to `chown -R myuser /home/myuser/mysite/public_html` to get it to work again.

Could it be something with permissions? Maybe misconfiguration in apache?

My `.htaccess` file hasn't been changed since it was last working properly, so I'm not too sure if that'd be the culprit.

---

In case it's important:

I'm running Apache2.2 on Debian Wheezy
My php.ini file is set to display errors
I have added `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` but still no errors
`php -l myfile.php` returns `No syntax errors detected in myfile.php`
Currently the file just contains `<?php echo "Test"; ?>` and still nothing.
The FTP user has proper permissions to upload, overwrite, delete files, and create/delete directories
I have tried deleting file/reuploading, restarting apache, and tried creating the file as root (using `vim`)
I have tried `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` to assure it wasn't just loading the cached version of the page
The rest of the site and subdomains work perfectly.

---

My `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file:

`[Mon Jul 27 05:16:45 2015] [error] [client] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jul 27 05:16:45 2015] [error] [client] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/path/to/dir/api/myfile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0`

---

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 https://my-main-site/404
ErrorDocument 403 https://my-main-site/404
ErrorDocument 500 https://my-main-site/500.shtml

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)/friends$ /profile.php?user=$1&friends [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^404$ /x/includes/errors/404.php [L]
```

---

Edit: Removing the file completely, and creating a new one as root works (displays in browser). However, I can't over-write/alter the file as FTP user.

Doing `chown www-data myFile.php` and/or `chown myftpuser myFile.php` both make the file not loadable again.

I just did chown myftpuser myFile.php again to give my ftp user back ownership/permissions to that file.

All of the other files/directories on the site are owned by my ftp user, so I don't see how this would happen.

Comment: post your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: DId you check the httpd and php error log files?

Comment: take a look in the apache error lock for further details

Comment: Sorry, updated question with `.htaccess` and `error.log` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add your FTP user to www-data group and make your project group readable/writeable.